# How to change a <div>'s style=width that is inside an ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, progress-bar

I have a Gridview and one of the columns needs to show progress on a set of tasks. I am using the bootstrap progress bar inside one of the gridview cells.

How do I change the div's `style="width: __%"` when it is inside a ItemTemplate which is inside a asp:TemplateField?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvExample" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField />
        <asp:BoundField />
        <asp:BoundField />                    
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="200">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div style="width: 50%" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" height: 20px;" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    <div id="ApprovedTherm" runat="server" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" height: 20px;" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    <div id="TotalTherm" runat="server" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" height: 20px;" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>            
</asp:GridView>
```

TLDR: How do I set div `style="width: __%"` from the code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by setting the attributes in code behind. But you need to add an `ID` and `runat=server` to the div first.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div id="ProgressBar" runat="server" style="width: 50%" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped"></div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Then in code behind use FindControl to locate the DIV and set the attributes.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    HtmlGenericControl hgc = row.FindControl("ProgressBar") as HtmlGenericControl;
    hgc.Attributes.Add("style", "width: 100%");
}
```

Or by index

```
HtmlGenericControl hgc = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("ProgressBar") as HtmlGenericControl
```

Comment: I tried that before and just tried it again to make sure. However, I keep getting "The server tag is not well formed." error message

Comment: That is because of this: `role="progressbar" height: 20px;"`. You are missing a `"`. But that height should be a style property anyways.

Answer (score 0):

1. Give id to DIV and run it on server

   ```
   <div id="temp" runat="server" ... > ... </div>
   ```
2. Get it from [RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event:

   ```
   protected void gvExample_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           // access the div here
           HtmlGenericControl tempDiv = (HtmlGenericControl) e.Row.FindControl("temp");
           tempDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "width: 50%;");
       }
   }
   ```

   **Note:** Don't forget to add `OnRowDataBound="gvExample_RowDataBound"` attribute to your GridView.

Comment: I keep getting The server tag is not well formed.